# html5 capture photo (<input />) immediately wihout asking for choosing exsiting photo

Tags: android, ios, html, mobile

I am developing a web application for mobile devices. To capture a photo I am using html5 feature - `input type="file" capture="camera"`

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*"  capture="camera" />
```

The problem is that it asks for choose between taking a new photo or choosing already existing photo.

[image]

Is there a possibility to launch camera for taking a new photo at once without asking this?
And is it possible to save photo which was taken without asking "Retake/Use photo"?

Comment: `capture="camera"` (String) has been replaced in the spec since 2012 with `capture="capture"` (Boolean)

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a possibility to launch camera for taking a new photo at once without asking this?

**Yes, but only on Android,** and it looks like this:

[image]

How: If `capture="capture"` (replaced `capture="camera"` in the spec) is part of the `input`'s attributes that's an indication that you want to capture straight from the camera. Android supports it, iOS ignores it, see [this article](https://blog.addpipe.com/correct-syntax-html-media-capture/) for details.

> And is it possible to save photo which was taken without asking "Retake/Use photo"?

No, the process & UI is controlled by the OS.

Disclaimer: Image courtesy of [Pipe](https://addpipe.com/), a company I'm CTO at and that handles video recording.